# Why dereference only to reference again in Go

Tags: go, gorilla

In [`gorilla/sessions`](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions) there is the following [code](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/store.go#L87):

```golang
func (s *CookieStore) New(r *http.Request, name string) (*Session, error) {
    session := NewSession(s, name)
    opts := *s.Options
    session.Options = &opts
    ...
```

Where `s.Options` is of type [`*sessions.Options`](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/options.go#L8):

```golang
type CookieStore struct {
    ...
    Options *Options // default configuration
}
```

And [`sessios.Session.Options`](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/sessions.go#L37) is also of type `*sessions.Options`:

```golang
type Session struct {
    ...
    Options *Options
    ...
}
```

My question is, what is the point of dereferencing `s.Options` and then assigning its reference to `session.Options`? Why not just do:

```golang
func (s *CookieStore) New(r *http.Request, name string) (*Session, error) {
    session := NewSession(s, name)
    session.Options = s.Options
    ...
```

Is this to make sure the dereferenced value of `s.Options` is copied over to `session.Options`, and not the actual reference therefore avoiding both objects pointing to the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is to prevent two pointers from pointing to the same location.

```
session := NewSession(s, name)
opts := *s.Options
```

At this point, `opts` contains a copy of `s.Options`. Then:

```
session.Options = &opts
```

This will set `session.Options` to an options object that is different from `s.Options`, but whose contents are initialized from `s.Options`.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I actually also found [this](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/request.go#L360) example in the source code that does the same thing.